# Defining data in classification trees: ordinal vs nominal

Tags: scikit-learn, decision-tree

My question is, when building a decision tree in sklearn, if I have a categorical variable, is there a problem if I manually input the values of the variable as numbers? (assuming the dataframe is small)
And, will there be difference in results if my variable is nominal or ordinal?

I don't think there should be much difference since the theory says that you should look for the best combination in terms of entropy and other metrics, so it shouldn't care if one value is smaller than another.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are differences if your categorical variable is ordinal or nominal:

If your variable is ordinal, you can just change each categories for a number (for example: bad, normal, good can be changed for 1,2,3). Note that you are keeping only one column. You can do it manually if you have few samples. You can use `LabelEncoder` from sklearn to do it.

If your variable is not ordinal you have to add new columns to you dataset, one for each category. You can do it manually, but I would recommend use `pd.get_dummies()`.

To sump up, you have to be very careful knowing if the categorical variable is ordinal or not. And you can deal with them manually (you would obtain same results), but it's recommend to use functions predefined to avoid some mistakes.

Comment: `OrdinalEncoder` would be preferred to `LabelEncoder` here.